# How to use Arrays.sort

Tags: arrays, sorting, compare, comparator

If I have following code:

```
    Arrays.sort(sums, new Comparator<Pair>() {
       public int compare(Pair a, Pair b) {
           return a.sum - b.sum;
       } 
    });
```

Is it sorting my values from small to large or from large to small? Also other than Comparator, is there anything else I can use to defind my sorter?

Comment: Why don't you print out the values and see for yourself?

Answer (score 0):

```
Arrays.sort(sums, new Comparator<Pair>() {
       public int compare(Pair a, Pair b) {
           return a.sum - b.sum;
       } 
    });
```

Walking through this code it simply compares each element one by one of **sums**.

Return statement result is definitive here. So it basically has 3 outputs.

If it returns a negative then the second one which is **b** in your case so it's smaller than a; put it on the head. Then it keeps comparing next element.

If it returns a positive then the first one is bigger then the second one. So it puts the **a** after **b**.

If it returns 0 then two of the elements compared are equal for the comparison property.

So as a result, if had a list of elements let's say.     `[3, 5, 2, 8]` it will become --> `[2, 3, 5, 8]`

It's totally up to you to compare against any property you want. 
I hope this explains things better.